# Gradle throws error org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain when cloning it using git submodule --init

Tags: git, gradle

I have private remote repository where are not only Java project, external dependencies, but also Gradle executables:

> gralde and gradle.bat

are located.
Before I clone the project I obtain external dependencies (Gradle as well):

```
git submodule update --init
```

I first time deal with this project and after I

```
git clone <project URL>
```

And proceed to the Gradle executable location and type:

```
./gradle -v
```

I get an errors:

> Error: Could not find or load main class
> org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain
>
> Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain

Colleague of mine, who has been working on this project couple months ago, after deleting the project and re-cloning it can successfully execute command:

```
./gradle -v
```

Second colleague, who's just like me has never been working on the project, tried to clone it and got same errors as I did.

However, when I tried to install Gradle (from gradle.org) on my PC and execute this command:

```
gradle -v
```

It executed sccessfully

This project don't assume you have Gradle pre-installed, nor Gradle config files, just raw git cloning should provide you with everything.

I thought maybe error in some ENV configuration, but after looking at mine and the colleague's where the Gradle works no special differences seen.

Any ideas where could hide a problem?? I saw a lot of resources, where mainly people suggest:

> 1. configure $PATH (but this should not be the solution, since all stuff is coming from remote repo)
> 2. configure build.gradle file (it could be a good solution, however, how does it work on my "first colleague's" PC and doesn't on mine (all
>    files are downloading at cloning)

So, I have no idea... Where is the problem? Is it still ENV problem or what?

Comment: So, you said that no big differences with ENV variables? Maybe issues in Git, I will post one, you could meet with this error, when dealing with large files (plenty of them)

Comment: @ojacomarket I just had no idea, what else can cause it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you feel that no ENV issues could cause it,
I would suggest to try this:

```
apt install git-lfs
```

This is not official Git "plugin", but it helps to handle large files, like video, audio, third-party libraries (your case) sometimes if your Git uses LFS it could cause problems when cloning the project

Ref: https://git-lfs.github.com/

UPD:your steps could look like:

> a) apt install git-lfs
>
> b) git clone ...

Comment: Solved my issue, grand merci! We also checked git config with my colleague and there was missing LFS on my pc